# Perl folding with perl_fold_blocks

Tags: vimrc, folding

I have the below settings in my .vimrc relating to Perl code folding.

When I type `za` to toggle folding, it works on any `sub { }` by just folding up the sub.

However, if I `za` a non-sub block (e.g. `if`<sup>*</sup> or `for` or `while`) it folds up the entire rest of the file, not just the block.

I just want to fold up the block. How might I achieve this?

```
" Perl auto-folding
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldlevelstart=3
let perl_fold = 1
let perl_fold_blocks = 1
```

* `if`s are officially statements rather than blocks in Perl, but I would still like to fold them.

Comment: I think this *may* just be a bug in the Perl folding, but I'm not sure ... You can perhaps look at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/perl.vim` line 426 ... Being a Perl hacker, you might have more luck deciphering the regexps that control this :-)

Comment: `za` toogles folds for the current line. I assume that the lines you are toggling on are not in any folds except for one big fold that includes the whole file. You can try `set foldcolumn=12` to better visualize how folds are nested.

Comment: Doing so will help you determine whether you want to adapt your understanding to account for how things currently work or to adapt perl's folding to better fit how you want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I use below commands for folding in perl

```
:set foldmarker={,}
:set foldmethod=marker
```

I believe this should work for your case as well.