# Is it possible folding blocks, comments and pod in perl

Tags: folding, filetype-perl

I have to edit some perl scripts. There I can fold **blocks** surrounded by "{}" with

```
:set foldmarker={,}
:set foldmethod=marker
```

See [Perl folding with perl_fold_blocks](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/perl-folding-with-perl-fold-blocks)

**Comments** starts with `#`. They should be folded, if there is more then one consecutive lines.

In some files there are **POD** sequences. They start with `=` in the first column and ends with `=cut` (starting in the first column too).

Between there may be different lines starting with `=`.

---

*Example:*

```pl
# Start of a comment
## second line
## third line

# ...
abc(1, 3);

=over 4

=item arguments

There are ...

 $a
 $b

=back

=cut
sub abc {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    # ...
}
```

So after folding there should be folded all

- between `=over 4` and `=cut`,
- from `sub abc {` to `}`, too. *To fold the sub works already* - and
- all from `Start of a comment` to `## third line`.

I expect something like

```txt
+---  3 lines: # Start of a comment ---------------------------------

# ...
abc(1, 3);

+--- 12 lines: =over 4 -----------------------------------------------
+---  4 lines: sub abc -----------------------------------------------
```

### Update:

I asked another question, where I hope to get the answere. There is an example of a session file.
[Folding problem with session](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/why-does-folding-doest-work-for-all-perl-files)

Comment: If you really want to use foldmethod=marker, then just add those markers in the regions that shall be folded

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - I want to be able to toggle fold with 'za' and best have an option to to close/open all. That 'za' works in `foldmethod=manual` too. So I can change it. But where to set the regions?

Comment: I found [How to fold C++-style comments in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280514/how-to-fold-c-style-comments-in-vim) to fold c++ comments, but I'm not able to use it for perl comments.

Comment: You could try syntax as a fold method; if the right groups have the fold property, it will just work

Comment: so what is the problem with adding those markers for the regions you want to have folded?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - The problem is, that I don't know how... To tell the truth, in march this year, I laught about the idea using vim. But now I think is the best for me. So I have much to learn! - And I can't find out how to set regions. - I tried `:set foldmarker={#,}#` and so on to do this, but it doesn't work.