# Why does folding not work for all Perl files?

Tags: folding, filetype-perl

I have 2 perl files opened in vim.
A test file `test.pl` and another perl file `Cbonusstat_TEC_bearb.pl`.

I made a session to save the environment. If I open vim with the session, the two files are loaded. With the testfile folding is possible (`sub { ... }` and pod `=xxx ... =cut`). With the other file folding doesn't work.

(There where other files used sooner, but closed now.)

(VIM v. 8.0.1453)

Can anyone tell me why folding works only on the testfile? What to do, using folding at the other file. And what to do opening other files with folding in common (perl files).

Here is the vim session file `fold_test`. Sorry it's very long, but I don't know, what is important.

```
let SessionLoad = 1
if &cp | set nocp | endif
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim
vmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
nmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
vnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis :call netrw#BrowseXVis()
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseX :call netrw#BrowseX(expand((exists("g:netrw_gx")? g:netrw_gx : '<cfile>')),netrw#CheckIfRemote())
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
set background=dark
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
set hlsearch
set nomodeline
set printoptions=paper:a4
set ruler
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
let s:so_save = &so | let s:siso_save = &siso | set so=0 siso=0
let v:this_session=expand("<sfile>:p")
silent only
cd /home2/oli/ab1000/prg.cust/Cbonusstat_TEC_au
if expand('%') == '' && !&modified && line('$') <= 1 && getline(1) == ''
  let s:wipebuf = bufnr('%')
endif
set shortmess=aoO
badd +368 20210716_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +62 Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +575 /home2/oli/ab1000/prg.cust/Cbonusgutschrift/Cbonusgutschrift.pl_fertig
badd +1 20210713_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +1 ~/test.pl
badd +1 20210714_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +126 /home2/oli/ab1000/prg.cust/contimp.pl
badd +1 20210715_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +199 /home2/oli/ab1000/prg.cust/Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +1 Cbonusstat_TEC_bearb.pl
badd +1 20210719_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
badd +263 CBONUS_01
badd +1 20210720_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
argglobal
silent! argdel *
$argadd 20210716_Cbonusstat_TEC.pl
set stal=2
edit Cbonusstat_TEC_bearb.pl
set splitbelow splitright
set nosplitbelow
set nosplitright
wincmd t
set winminheight=1 winheight=1 winminwidth=1 winwidth=1
argglobal
setlocal keymap=
setlocal noarabic
setlocal noautoindent
setlocal backupcopy=
setlocal balloonexpr=
setlocal nobinary
setlocal nobreakindent
setlocal breakindentopt=
setlocal bufhidden=
setlocal buflisted
setlocal buftype=
setlocal nocindent
setlocal cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal cinoptions=
setlocal cinwords=if,else,while,do,for,switch
set colorcolumn=120
setlocal colorcolumn=120
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
setlocal commentstring=/*%s*/
setlocal complete=.,w,b,u,t,i
setlocal concealcursor=
setlocal conceallevel=0
setlocal completefunc=
setlocal nocopyindent
setlocal cryptmethod=
setlocal nocursorbind
setlocal nocursorcolumn
setlocal nocursorline
setlocal define=
setlocal dictionary=
setlocal nodiff
setlocal equalprg=
setlocal errorformat=
setlocal noexpandtab
if &filetype != 'perl'
setlocal filetype=perl
endif
setlocal fixendofline
setlocal foldcolumn=0
setlocal foldenable
setlocal foldexpr=0
setlocal foldignore=#
setlocal foldlevel=0
setlocal foldmarker={{{,}}}
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
setlocal foldminlines=1
setlocal foldnestmax=20
setlocal foldtext=foldtext()
setlocal formatexpr=
setlocal formatoptions=tcq
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+[\\]:.)}\\t\ ]\\s*
setlocal formatprg=
setlocal grepprg=
setlocal iminsert=0
setlocal imsearch=-1
setlocal include=
setlocal includeexpr=
setlocal indentexpr=
setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal noinfercase
setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
setlocal keywordprg=
setlocal nolinebreak
setlocal nolisp
setlocal lispwords=
setlocal nolist
setlocal makeencoding=
setlocal makeprg=
setlocal matchpairs=(:),{:},[:]
setlocal nomodeline
setlocal modifiable
setlocal nrformats=bin,octal,hex
setlocal nonumber
setlocal numberwidth=4
setlocal omnifunc=
setlocal path=
setlocal nopreserveindent
setlocal nopreviewwindow
setlocal quoteescape=\\
setlocal noreadonly
setlocal norelativenumber
setlocal norightleft
setlocal rightleftcmd=search
setlocal noscrollbind
setlocal shiftwidth=8
setlocal noshortname
setlocal signcolumn=auto
setlocal nosmartindent
setlocal softtabstop=0
setlocal nospell
setlocal spellcapcheck=[.?!]\\_[\\])'\"\    \ ]\\+
setlocal spellfile=
setlocal spelllang=en
setlocal statusline=
setlocal suffixesadd=
setlocal swapfile
setlocal synmaxcol=3000
if &syntax != 'perl'
setlocal syntax=perl
endif
setlocal tabstop=8
setlocal tagcase=
setlocal tags=
setlocal termkey=
setlocal termsize=
setlocal textwidth=0
setlocal thesaurus=
setlocal noundofile
setlocal undolevels=-123456
setlocal nowinfixheight
setlocal nowinfixwidth
setlocal wrap
setlocal wrapmargin=0
let s:l = 373 - ((23 * winheight(0) + 25) / 51)
if s:l < 1 | let s:l = 1 | endif
exe s:l
normal! zt
373
normal! 0
tabedit ~/test.pl
set splitbelow splitright
set nosplitbelow
set nosplitright
wincmd t
set winminheight=1 winheight=1 winminwidth=1 winwidth=1
argglobal
setlocal keymap=
setlocal noarabic
setlocal noautoindent
setlocal backupcopy=
setlocal balloonexpr=
setlocal nobinary
setlocal nobreakindent
setlocal breakindentopt=
setlocal bufhidden=
setlocal buflisted
setlocal buftype=
setlocal nocindent
setlocal cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal cinoptions=
setlocal cinwords=if,else,while,do,for,switch
set colorcolumn=120
setlocal colorcolumn=120
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
setlocal commentstring=/*%s*/
setlocal complete=.,w,b,u,t,i
setlocal concealcursor=
setlocal conceallevel=0
setlocal completefunc=
setlocal nocopyindent
setlocal cryptmethod=
setlocal nocursorbind
setlocal nocursorcolumn
setlocal nocursorline
setlocal define=
setlocal dictionary=
setlocal nodiff
setlocal equalprg=
setlocal errorformat=
setlocal noexpandtab
if &filetype != 'perl'
setlocal filetype=perl
endif
setlocal fixendofline
setlocal foldcolumn=0
setlocal foldenable
setlocal foldexpr=0
setlocal foldignore=#
setlocal foldlevel=0
setlocal foldmarker={{{,}}}
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
setlocal foldminlines=1
setlocal foldnestmax=20
setlocal foldtext=foldtext()
setlocal formatexpr=
setlocal formatoptions=tcq
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+[\\]:.)}\\t\ ]\\s*
setlocal formatprg=
setlocal grepprg=
setlocal iminsert=0
setlocal imsearch=-1
setlocal include=
setlocal includeexpr=
setlocal indentexpr=
setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal noinfercase
setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
setlocal keywordprg=
setlocal nolinebreak
setlocal nolisp
setlocal lispwords=
setlocal nolist
setlocal makeencoding=
setlocal makeprg=
setlocal matchpairs=(:),{:},[:]
setlocal nomodeline
setlocal modifiable
setlocal nrformats=bin,octal,hex
setlocal nonumber
setlocal numberwidth=4
setlocal omnifunc=
setlocal path=
setlocal nopreserveindent
setlocal nopreviewwindow
setlocal quoteescape=\\
setlocal noreadonly
setlocal norelativenumber
setlocal norightleft
setlocal rightleftcmd=search
setlocal noscrollbind
setlocal shiftwidth=8
setlocal noshortname
setlocal signcolumn=auto
setlocal nosmartindent
setlocal softtabstop=0
setlocal nospell
setlocal spellcapcheck=[.?!]\\_[\\])'\"\    \ ]\\+
setlocal spellfile=
setlocal spelllang=en
setlocal statusline=
setlocal suffixesadd=
setlocal swapfile
setlocal synmaxcol=3000
if &syntax != 'perl'
setlocal syntax=perl
endif
setlocal tabstop=8
setlocal tagcase=
setlocal tags=
setlocal termkey=
setlocal termsize=
setlocal textwidth=0
setlocal thesaurus=
setlocal noundofile
setlocal undolevels=-123456
setlocal nowinfixheight
setlocal nowinfixwidth
setlocal wrap
setlocal wrapmargin=0
let s:l = 28 - ((27 * winheight(0) + 25) / 51)
if s:l < 1 | let s:l = 1 | endif
exe s:l
normal! zt
28
normal! 0
tabnext 2
set stal=1
if exists('s:wipebuf')
  silent exe 'bwipe ' . s:wipebuf
endif
unlet! s:wipebuf
set winheight=1 winwidth=20 shortmess=filnxtToO
set winminheight=1 winminwidth=1
let s:sx = expand("<sfile>:p:r")."x.vim"
if file_readable(s:sx)
  exe "source " . fnameescape(s:sx)
endif
let &so = s:so_save | let &siso = s:siso_save
doautoall SessionLoadPost
unlet SessionLoad
" vim: set ft=vim :
```

### Update

Even without using sessions: The on the testfile folding works out of the box, at the other one not. If I enter <kbd>:e</kbd>, folding works there too. (Thanks to Maxim Kim :). But why?

Comment: Is the issue only when using sessions? What is the output of `:verbose set foldmethod?` in the window w/o folding? What if you save the same session but files are loaded into split windows? Did you try latest vim version?

Comment: @MaximKim - If I load the file direct, without a session, foldmethod is "manual". If I set it to "syntax", nothing happens, `:verbose set foldmethod` outputs `foldmethod=syntax` then. - Then I open the "test.pl" file in split screen and there it works. `:verbose set foldmethod` outputs `foldmethod=syntax` and `Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/perl.vim`

Comment: I guess you have `let g:perl_fold = 1` somewhere in your vimrc. When you `:e test.pl` your filetype should be set up as `perl`. When filetype is set, syntax file is loaded. In case of perl syntax file it checks for `g:perl_fold` var existence and enables folding with `foldmethod=syntax`. *What exactly you do when "load the file directly"?*

Comment: @MaximKim - "Load the file directly" means: `vim Cbonusstat_TEC.pl`. Then opend the other file: `:vsplit ~/test.pl`. On "test.pl" folding works then. **But** it's the same vice versa! If I open the testfile first (`vim ~/test.pl`) and then the other one (`:vsplit Cbonusstat_TEC_bearb.pl`), then "Cbonusstat_TEC_bearb.pl" works and testfile does not. (It seems, that the foldmethod of the first file is always "manual" and of the second (in split pane) "syntax". But nothing changes if I type `:set foldmethod=syntax`.)